# ReadStream Error event not including stack trace?

Tags: node.js

This might be a dumb question. But I can't find any information on it. I'm surprised to see that the following code does not provide a stack trace.

```
try {
    const readStream = fs.createReadStream('file-that-does-not-exist');

    readStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
        console.log(`Received ${chunk.length} bytes of data.`);
    });
    readStream.on('error', (error) => {
        console.log('on error:', error);
    });
    readStream.on('end', () => {
        console.log('end');
    });

} catch (error) {
    console.log('catch error:', error);
    process.exit(1);
}
```

This results in:

```
on error: { Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'file-that-does-not-exist'
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'file-that-does-not-exist' }
```

I understand that the readable does not call data nor end due to there being no data to process. The error event is emitted because there is no file. I'm surprised that the error object does not include the stack trace.

Does anyone know the underlaying cause of this? I can't find it anywhere in the documentation.
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_readstream
https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable

I understand that the stack trace is optional https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error but the stack trace is nearly always normally included.

Using Node.js >9